# Pre-loaded image in cropperjs

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I am using following example for image editing for my website which is developed in vue.js and drag and drop Image up-loader. I want to remove Image upload functionality and want to use a preload fixed image which is store in file system.

Source available:-https://github.com/fengyuanchen/photo-editor

Demo Available- https://fengyuanchen.github.io/photo-editor/

I tried to put direct Image path but it does not work :-

```
 <div id="app">
    <div>
        <img id="image" src="picture.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: Still drag and drop box is appearing.

Comment: You can load the stored image and put class 'hidden' on the input form.